# Proving $\{f_n(z)=e^{-(z-n)^2}\}$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Show that the sequence of functions $\{f_n(z)=e^{-(z-n)^2}\}$ converges uniformly on the set $E=D(0,1)$.

$|e^{-(z-n)^2}-0|=|e^{-z^2}.e^{-n^2}.e^{2nz}|\leqslant |e^{-n^2}.e^{2nz}| $

However I do not know how to proceed.

**Questions:**

Is the proof right till the last step? How should I finish the proof?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no, it's not true that $e^{-z^2}\le 1$ on the disk. The actual worst case is at $z=\pm i$. Correcting that and estimating the $e^{2nz}$ term for good measure,
$$\left|e^{-(z-n)^2}\right| = \left|e^{-z^2}\cdot e^{-n^2}\cdot e^{2nz}\right| \le \sup_z \left|e^{-z^2}\right|\cdot e^{-n^2}\cdot\sup_z\left|e^{2nz}\right| = e^1\cdot e^{-n^2}\cdot e^{2n}$$
Now, show that goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

$|f_n(z)|=e^{-n^{2} \Re (\frac z n-1)^{2}}$ and $\Re (\frac z n-1)^{2} >\frac 1 2$ for $|z|<1$ and $n$ sufficiently large. Can you finish the proof from here

Comment: In fact, $\Re (\frac z n-1)^{2} \geq \frac 1 2$ for every $n$ if $|z|<1$. Use the fact that $|1-(\frac z n-1)^{2}|=|\frac {z^{2}} {n^{2}}-2\frac z n|\leq \frac 1 n +|\frac 1 {n^{2}}\leq \frac 1 2$